# Ajax calls destroying session data unintentionaly

Tags: php, ajax, session, datatables

I am storing information about a user in session data.  One of my webpages, let's call it `table.php` is a table (using datatables) of pies.  `table.php` is using datatables ajax serverside feature and is accessing a script called `serverside.php`.  Now in order to make sure that the user is allowed to view the table, both `table.php` and `serverside.php` start the session and check user variables.  This works, but about 1 out of every 15 refreshed of `table.php` will result in all session data being deleted.  Why is this happening?

The same session code works fine with other ajax scripts.  But the tables screws everything up.

Could it be because the ajax script is being called at virtually the same time as `table.php`?

init and dinit and the code segments below simply are used to instantiate and later unset variables that cannot be serialized (like PDO).  dinit also contains `session_write_close()`;

Table.php looks something like this:

```
<?php
Define("EXEC",true);

include('/var/www/private/core/AutoLoader.php');
\helpers\SessionManager::start('A Name');
$_SESSION['User']->init();

if ($_SESSION['User']->getPermissions() > 1) {
    $_SESSION['User']->dinit();
    die("You must be an admin to access this site");
}
?>

<table id="items" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>View</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>View</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#items").dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "/serverside.php",
            "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 20, -1], [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"]],
            "displayLength": 10,
            "stateSave": true,
            "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                if (data[3] == 1) {
                    $(row).addClass("enabled");
                } else {
                    $(row).addClass("disabled");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
$_SESSION['User']->dinit();
?>
```

ServerSide.php looks something like this:

```
<?php
define("EXEC", true);

require_once('/var/www/private/core/AutoLoader.php');

\helpers\SessionManager::start('A Name');
$_SESSION['User']->init();

if ($_SESSION['User']->getPermissions() > 1) {
    $_SESSION['User']->dinit();
    die("You must be an admin to access this site");
}

class SSP {
    public static function simple(PARAMTERS)
        This function works, a bunch of code here
}

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
$_SESSION['User']->dinit();
?>
```

The SessionManager Class

```
<?php

namespace helpers;

use \library\User;

/**
*   Session Manager to ensure security and make easy functions
*   @author Help from http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions
**/
class SessionManager {

    /**
    *   Session start function
    *   @param $limit time to maintain session
    *   @param $path the path under the domain for which it should work
    *   @param $secure SLL override
    **/
    public static function start($name,$limit = 0, $path = '/', $secure = null) {
        // Run session_start() Wrapper
        self::sessionStart($name,$limit,$path,$secure);

        if (!self::isSessionStarted()) {
            echo "NEW";
            self::destroySession();
            self::sessionStart($name,$limit,$path,$secure);
            self::createNewUser();
        } else if (rand(1,100) <= 5) {
            session_regenerate_id();
        }

        //print_r($_SESSION);
    }

    /**
    *   Create the new session for this user
    **/
    private static function createNewUser() {
        $_SESSION = [];
        $_SESSION['User'] = new \library\User($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    }

    /**
    *   Session Start Wrapper to define cookie paramters
    *   @param $limit time to maintain session
    *   @param $path the path under the domain for which it should work
    *   @param $secure SLL override
    **/
    private static function sessionStart($name,$limit = 0, $path = '/', $secure = null) {
        // Set the name of the Session
        session_name($name);

        // Set domain name for cookie to work under
        $domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        //Parent Domain Modification
        $domain = explode(".", $domain);
        $domain = "." . $domain[count($domain) - 2] . "." . $domain[count($domain) - 1];

        // Set the default secure value to whether the site is being accessed with SSL
        $https = isset($secure) ? $secure : isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']);

        // Set the cookie settings and start the session
        session_set_cookie_params($limit, $path, $domain, $https, true);
        session_start();
    }

    /**
    *   Destroy the session
    **/
    public static function destroySession() {
        $_SESSION[] = [];
        session_destroy();
    }

    /**
    *   @return Boolean value of it the session has proper variables
    **/
    private static function isSessionStarted() {
        return isset($_SESSION['User']) && $_SESSION['User'] instanceof User;
    }
}
?>
```

**EDIT:**  Adding `async: false` did not help.

Comment: Please show your sample code. We cannot answer you question by guesting the codes in you `serverside.php` and the `table.php`. These two  file might have a code that can cause to delete your session

Comment: @RomnickSusa Yea you are correct, I will edit my post.  I was just attempting to see if maybe this was a known issue.

Comment: @RomnickSusa I hope it is not too much to sift through, let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Out of pure curiosity if you set `async: false`(or whatever the norm is now for sync calls) to the ajax, do you still lose the session data?

Comment: @Andrew Not sure what you mean.  How/where do I set that to false?

Comment: I believe @Andrew meant `"ajax": { "url": "/serverside.php", "async": false },` in DataTables initialization code.

Comment: @Andrew Adding the async false did not work